# How can I edit the export templates for SQL-Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

when I run an export from SQL Developer I run into a Flyway problem. This is because the export contains an unnecessary keyword that Flyway cannot handle. I tend to forget this so I'd rather avoid this keyword to be added.

When I call the following code:

```
create procedure do_nothing
as
begin
  null;
end;
```

This is exactly what SQL Developer shows me when I open up the code. When I click on 'export', however, I get the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Procedure DO_NOTHING
--------------------------------------------------------
set define off;

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "POSITION_REPORTING"."DO_NOTHING" 
as
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

I want to get rid of 'EDITIONABLE' and I hope this is possible via some setting in SQL-Developer.

Answer (score 2):

Procedures weren't editionable before 12c, so it's a bit of a hack but you could tell SQL Devleoper to export 11g-compatible code; in the export dialog change `COMPATIBLE` to `11.2`:

[image]

The code in the exported file then omits `EDITIONABLE`, as it knows it isn't valid for that version.

This isn't something you can set in the preferences, which makes sense since the list of valid versions will depend on the version of the database you're exporting from. You probably wouldn't want to permanently set that to a lower version anyway.

The export tool uses the `dbms_metadata` package to actually produce the code, so an alternative is to write your own export process that uses that package, and specify the version through that:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
  object_type => 'PROCEDURE',
  name => 'DO_NOTHING',
  version => '11.2')
from dual;
```

which produces the same output as the export, except for the comments and the `set define off` line:

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(OBJECT_TYPE=>'PROCEDURE',NAME=>'DO_NOTHING',VERSION=>'11.2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "HR"."DO_NOTHING" 
as
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - a hack to work around whatever Flyway's problem is *8-) I have no idea, there may be other 12c-related changes it does need to know about, but I suspect it (or the version being used) just doesn't know about 12c at all.

Comment: @AlexPoole I was only sore as I went to take screenshots and paste my answer to see that you beat me to it :)

Comment: I hope you also added the [obligatory freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/152099) to yours... *8-)

Comment: Good enough *8-)

Comment: So it looks like my SQL Developer version does not give me the opportunity to select the version, the dropdown is missing in the export wizzard. I'll return to 'discipline' then.